# Why isn't rng-tools installed by default on all OS?

Tags: linux, random

Many Linux distributions use the package rng-tools, but why isn't it always installed by default? It would increase entropy (`/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`) greatly!

Is there any security reason for why it isn't installed by default? Not trusting the `/dev/hwrng`?

Comment: This question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39992/is-it-safe-to-use-rng-tools-on-a-virtual-machine might give one reason

Comment: See also this question: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/96741/3365